# how to append a html tag from an ajax call response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

**I have an ajax function :**

```
$('#app-name').change(function () {//1
  console.log("inside change");
  var applname= this.value;
  console.log(applname);
  $.ajax({//2
    url: 'foo',
    method : 'GET',
    dataType : "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: {"AppID":"appname"},
    success: function(data){
      var order_data = data;
      $('#foo-name').html('');
      $.each(order_data, function(i, item) {//3
        console.log(order_data[i]);
        $('<option value='+ order_data[i] +'>'+order_data[i]).html('</options>').appendTo('#foo-name');
      });//3 
    }
  });//2
});//1
```

This function is doing everything else except appending value to the html. 
Am i doing it wrong? Can you help solve this issues.

Comment: technically speaking, you shouldn't be modifying the DOM In a loop like that. every time you do .appendTo(), the dom has to be modified, triggering a re-rendering, blah blah blah. it's very inefficient. you should build up a single string containing all of your options, then stuff the string into the dom in a single operation, triggering the redrawing ONCE.

Comment: $().html inserts html into a container, so no need to use it along with .append().

Comment: @Buffalo there is in the OPs case, as the `html('')` removes existing options before appending the new ones. Admittedly there's better patterns to follow, but that's why the OPs code works like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the closing `</option` tag in the jQuery object you create. Don't set it through the `html()` method. Try this:

```
$('<option value="' + order_data[i] + '">' + order_data[i] + '</option>').appendTo('#foo-name');
```

That said, you can also improve performance of your code by building the string in the loop and appending it to the `select` once, like this:

```
success: function(data) {
    var options = '';
    $.each(data.split(/\n/), function(i, item) {
        options += '<option value=' + item.trim() + '>' + item.trim() + '</option>');
    });
    $('#foo-name').html(options);
}
```

*Update* You also need to `split()` the text you state that you're returning before looping through it.

Comment: no its not working. i'm not sure what's wrong. i have removed the ')' from </option>'); but still my drop down list is still showing empty

Comment: the program runs perfectly but no elements in the drop down list where the `id=foo-name`

Comment: Are you sure your AJAX request is returning data then?

Comment: I think your data value shouldn't include `" "` ,just use `applname`

Comment: yes i have printed it in the console and the data is there.

Comment: What does the data look like? Please edit your question to include it

Comment: this is the console :
`inside change\n
SOURCE\n
FORD\n
HR\n
SCOTT\n
SH\n
OE\n
PM\n
IX`

Comment: So you're returning plain text, not JSON or XML? I updated the answer in that case

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code in your ajax success event.

```
success: function(data) {
    var _html = '';
    $.each(order_data, function(i, item) {
        _html += '<option value='+ item +'>'+item+'</options>';
    });
    $('#foo-name').append(_html);
}
```